# Angular not parsing JSON into object

Tags: c#, json, angular

Can someone explain why my JSON object isnt being correctly parsed into an Angular object? (the Angular object values are empty when I display HTML)

**Angular code making request for JSON**

```
GetMessageSub(): void {
  this.http.get('http://localhost:61460/api/values')
    .pipe(map(res => JSON.parse(res.toString())),
        catchError(this.handleError('getMessageSub()', [])))
    .subscribe(people => this.people = people);
}
```

**C# code that is replying with a JSON**

```
public JsonResult Get()
{
    return Json("[{ id:1, name:\"value2\" }]");
}
```

**Angular code that declares a People object**

```
export class People {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  }
```

**HTML that calls the people object (which is populated by GetMessageSub()**

```
people found:  {{people.id}} -- {{people.name}}
```

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, so it’s already a object. There is no need to convert it

Comment: @SandipNirmal Not quite. JSON is a format for a string. Something must parse it to get it into an object. Angular does that automatically in most cases, but it's not because JSON is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C# code:

```
return Json("[{ id:1, name:\"value2\" }]");
```

returns a string, `"[{ id:1, name:\"value2\" }]"`, encoded as JSON, so `"\"[{ id:1, name:\\\"value2\\\" }]\""`, not an array with a single object. If you want to do that, either:

Build an array of objects in C# and send that through JSON:

```
return Json(new object[] { new { id = 1, name = "value2" } });
```

Or send it as a string using a `ContentResult`:

```
return Content("[{ id:1, name:\"value2\" }]", "application/json");
```

You'd need to change the signature of your method as well for the latter option.

Comment: I tried having c# return an array of objects like you suggested, but my HTML output was odd: `people found: function People() { }:: -- People`. I included the HTML call above that generated the output in my post

Comment: Note a couple of things: Angular allows you to use `res.json()` to get the object parsed from the JSON (so, `map(res => res.json())`). Also, `people` is going to be an array. Arrays generally don't have `id` or `name` attributes. You'll likely need an `*ngFor` to iterate through the items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You are already returning a valid JSON, no need to parse, just assign

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:61460/api/values')
    .pipe(map(res =>res)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getMessageSub()', [])))
    .subscribe(people => this.people = people);
```